# changing array elements but keeping index keys, php

Tags: php

I am having some issue about index keys. I have array which has contain urls. So I need to edit elements in that array. And change the the old elements with the new ones. But the new elements coming with new index keys(it's a normal thing.) Actually, I want to pass old element's key to new one. There is simple example for what am I am doing...

my array `$urls` is below.

```
  [0]=>
  string(34) "helloworld.com/"
  [1]=>
  string(34) "exampleworld.com/"
  [2]=>
  string(26) "new-exampleworld.com/"
```

now editing and unset the old elements.

```
foreach($urls as $k => $val){
  $urls[] = $val . outline;
  unset($urls[$k]);
}
```

So the outputs is like

```
  [3]=>
  string(34) "helloworld.com/outline"
  [4]=>
  string(34) "exampleworld.com/outline"
  [5]=>
  string(26) "new-exampleworld.com/outline"
```

The problem here, it's adding new element next. But actually, I want to change it with editted one. Because I need to keep index keys same... is there anyway to do add change new elements with the old ones. NOT adding next.

Comment: $urls[$k] = $val . outline;

Comment: And remove the `unset($urls[$k]);`

Comment: Why not directly assign the values? Perhaps `$urls[$k] = $val . "outline";` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
print_r(preg_filter('/$/', 'outline', [
   'helloworld.com/',
   'exampleworld.com/',
   'new-exampleworld.com/',
]));
```

output

```
Array
(
    [0] => helloworld.com/outline
    [1] => exampleworld.com/outline
    [2] => new-exampleworld.com/outline
)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7e373b9623eb90a7694eae76512452e23f0aec8f)

So in your case (preg_filter is kind of a trick for prefixing, suffixing arrays):

```
$urls = preg_filter('/$/','outline',$urls);
```

The `/$/` is a Regular expression, or a pattern to match. In this case `$` just matches the end of the string, and the second argument replaces that with `outline`.  Basically, I should mention you can't really replace the end of a string.  It's just a fact that the string ends, plus the `$` doesn't capture any characters to replace... but I digress.

**In your original code**

```
foreach($urls as $k => &$val){
    $val .= 'outline';
}
```

Use the `&` pass by reference, to update it directly.  References without getting too deep, are like a pointer to the actual variable.  So this basically says to use the array and not a copy of it.  That way we can just assign (or append) to the string and we don't have to make any lookups in the original array or make a new array etc.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's a nice and complete answer, this one should be the accepted one

Answer (score 2):

You are creating new indexes then removing the old ones. This behaviour is normal.

If you just want to modify the values, then... modify them

in example :

```
foreach($urls as $k => $val){
  $urls[$k] = $val . "outline";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to modify the value and keep the index , you can do a Pass by reference in foreach

```
<?php
$urls =["google"=>"google.com","Facebook.com",1=>"yahoo.com"];

print_r($urls);
// For updating values  

foreach($urls as &$url)
{
    $url = $url ."\\new_url";
}

echo "<br>";
print_r($urls);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

[array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) is probably a good way to do it.
You apply a function to every member of an array. So this code:

```
<?php
    $urls = array( 'helloworld.com/', 'exampleworld.com/', 'new-exampleworld.com/' );
    array_walk($urls, function ( &$item1, $key ) {
        $item1 = $item1 . 'outline';
    });
    print_r( $urls );
?>
```

will output this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => helloworld.com/outline
    [1] => exampleworld.com/outline
    [2] => new-exampleworld.com/outline
)
```

If the function need to be more complex or reusable, it is better not to use an anonymous function like I did above.
Do it like this (and you can pass different suffix if needed):

```php
    function add_postfix( &$item, $key, $suffix ) {
        $item1 = $item . $suffix;
    };

    array_walk( $urls, 'add_postfix', 'outline' );
```